# How to change the system locale on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cygwin

On windows 7, I would like to change the system locale from the command line without restarting. Is there any windows command line utility or the one in cygwin that I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722068(v=ws.10).aspx) has information of how to change system locale kind of information from the command-line using the `intlcfg.exe` command.

An example command for you could be as follows, which would change `syslocale` to US-english `en-US`.

```
intlcfg.exe –syslocale:en-US
```

NOTE: You may still need to reboot for the settings to take effect, have not tried this so unsure about this part.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a quick Google search turned up a lot of results with different ways to do it.

[This TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722068%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) details how to use the Intlcfg command to change settings such as the Locale

> Update language and locale settings
>
> intlcfg.exe [-all:language_name] [-uilang:language_name] [uilangfallback:language_name] [-syslocale:language_name][-userlocale:language_name] [-inputlocale:default_keyboard_description; keyboard_description or locale_name] [-userhive:registry_path] [-syshive:registry_path] [-swhive:registry_path] [-image:path] [-dist:path] [-silent] [-skudefaults:language]

[This article on AutoIt.com](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/118706-fastest-way-command-line-to-change-system-locale/) talks about setting up XML files and creating a script to switch between them.

It's hard to quote, but the gist is:

1. Create a text file with the settings
2. Use rundll32 to apply the changes to the registry